# JS: How to return 'undefined' instead of throwing error 'cannot read property x of undefined'

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to have js return undefined rather than throw an error when a parent property does not exist?

Example

```
a = {}
b = a.x.y.z
// Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
// Target result: b = undefined
```

Comment: If you don't want to fill your code with a lot of `try`/`catch` (that is somehow a solution), in JS usually you check if an object is defined before using a specific property / method of it. It means, in that case, that you should verify that `a` has `x`, before access to it, and so on. If you using that approach to simulate namespaces, you can create your own function that do this operation recursively for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check for the existence of each property:

```
var b;
if (a.x && a.x.y && a.x.y.z) {
    b = a.x.y.z
}
```

Or, simliar to another poster's "safeGet" function:

```
var get = function (obj, ns) {
    var y = ns.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i += 1) {
        if (obj[y[i]]) {
            obj = obj[y[i]];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Use:

```
var b = get(a, 'x.y.z');
```

Comment: I normally do this except that there are a large number of properties (out of my control, it gets the data structure from elsewhere) and wanted a shorter/cleaner way to do it

Comment: What do you think of my other suggestion?

Comment: Yes; it's kind of a hack, but you'd call it as: `get(someVar, 'x.y.0.z')`.

Comment: this would still blow up, you'd need to use the `typeof` operator.

Comment: @jbabey Can you provide an example that "blows up?"

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
  a = {}
  b = a.x.y.z
}
catch (e) {
  b = void 0;
}
```

Comment: @arcyqwerty I guess you could do `if ( e instanceof TypeError )`

Comment: yeah. suppose it works pretty well. adding a `throw e` to it if false

Answer (score 2):

I would go for slightly verbose:

```
var b = ((a.x || {}).y || {}).z
```

Answer (score 1):

you could write a `safeGet` helper function, something like:

edited for drilldown as suggested in comments by arcyqwerty

```
var getter = function (collection, key) {
    if (collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return collection[key];
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
};

var drillDown = function (keys, currentIndex, collection) {
    var max = keys.length - 1;
    var key = keys[currentIndex];

    if (typeof collection === 'undefined') {
        return undefined;   
    }

    if (currentIndex === max) {
        return getter(collection, key);
    } else {
        return drillDown(keys, currentIndex + 1,
                         getter(collection, key));
    }
};

var safeGet = function (collection, key) {
    if (key.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        return drillDown(key.split("."), 0, collection);
    } else {
        return getter(collection, key);
    }
};

a = { x: 1 };
b = safeGet(a, 'x.y.z');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YqdWH/2/

Comment: Needs to work for many nested keys, multiple calls to safeget would probably be a bit long

Comment: @arcyqwerty that can be easily taken care of by parsing the key into parts separated by `.` and recursively calling safeGet